# slick: Way to get the column names from stored procedure execution

Tags: sql-server, playframework, slick

I cant find a way to get the column names/header data from stored procedure execution. I just get the row data.

I am executing the stored this way in scala slick:
sql"stored_procedure_name @param=something"

Please let me know if Slick supports this already or if this is something that has to be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON;

SET FMTONLY ON;

exec sys.sp_catalogs @server_name=NULL
```

`sys.sp_catalogs` is a system stored procedure in Master, replace it with your stored procedure.

Comment: When I run the stored procedure from SQL developer, I do see the header info. This is a problem with Slick's driver specifically, where are no methods that seem to return the header/metadata info.

Comment: CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GET_COLUMNS
@ table NVARCHAR(50)
AS
SELECT column_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table
EXEC sp_GET_COLUMNS 'your_table_name'